# Trying to undertand if a noun an be an adverb given the struture of a sentence

Tags: verbs, nouns, adverbs

I'm trying to teach my 7 year old daughter English and am clearly failing given I'm asking a question here.

The following sentence has me a little baffled in regards to the noun, verb and adverb.

> My sister plays at home

If it were

> My sister plays outside

Then I know the noun (well, noun phrase) is *My sister*, the verb is *plays* and the adverb is *outside*.

In the case of *My sister plays at home*, it could there are 2 nouns. Both *Sister* and *home* could be nouns, but given the sentence structure, I feel only *sister* is the noun.

So, given the sentence *My sister plays at home*, I think the noun phrase is *My sister*, the verb is *plays* and the adverb is *at home*.

Is this correct?

Comment: Look up "prepositional phrase".

Comment: So it's an adverbial phrase? @HotLicks

Comment: @HotLicks it’s not a prepositional phrase (PP), if *outside* is followed by a noun, it’s a PP “*outside* the house” etc. If it’s by itself and doesn’t follow a noun, it’s an adverb. [Source](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/outside)

Comment: @aesking - The question was about "My sister plays at home".

Comment: It's a prepositional phrase functioning as an adverb to answer the question of *where* for the verb: plays where? plays at home. (At least that's close enough, for a seven-year-old's purposes.)

Comment: Why would you teach a 7 year old grammar at this level? It's unnecessary to be able to speak fluently. In fact, I'd say it's a hindrance. Most 7 year old native speakers know little to no grammatical theory.

Comment: @CJDennis are you asking me? If so, I'm not. But I don't want to her to learn the wrong thing either. It's important I understand so when she says "is this right", I know how to answer her.

Answer (score 1):

In:

> **My sister** [S] **plays** [Intransitive Verb] **at home** [Prepositional phrase (PP) functioning as an *adverbial phrase*]

There is no direct object as “at home” is not the direct object of “plays”

So what you have here is the PP  “at home” is functioning as an adverbial phrase (note: the difference between adverb and adverbial phrase) to describe the adverb of location (Where? = at home).

“home” is the object of the preposition of “at” and does not receive the action of the verb.

> “At home” can also be analysed as prepositional phrases which act as verb-phrase complements (by some grammars, especially CaGEL p. 54: Complements with the form of PPs, which class it as a “non-core complement”) to the verb:
>
> - He never *abides* ***by*** the rules.
> - She *contributed* ***to*** the project.
> - I *disagree* ***with*** your analysis.
> - Mothers sometimes *gripe* ***at*** their children.
> - The council *objects* ***to*** your hostility.
>
> A/N: They are complements because  the complement clause (CC) are selected by their verb and without the CC in the sentence above; they are rendered ungrammatical.
>
> Furthermore as stated by @BillJ [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/517119/call-on-trans-or-intransitive-verb/517137#517137), “complements of prepositions are not direct or indirect objects”.
>
> Source: https://parentingpatch.com/using-prepositional-phrases-verb-phrase-complements/

While, in:

> **My sister** [S] **plays** [I.V.] **outside** [adverb]

The verb “plays” is intransitive, outside is a **locative adverb**. “Outside” is not the direct object of “plays”.

> Where play has a direct object:
>
> - Play *baseball*
> - Playing *children*
> - Children playing *house*
> - Playing *a trick*.

Comment: << “At home” can also be analysed as prepositional phrases which act as verb-phrase complements to the verb:

He never abides by the rules.... >>  // There is no complement in 'My sister paints at home', and you need to explain why you think 'My sister plays at home' may have a different deep structure (if what you're trying to say here is what I think it is).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth According to CaGEL, “My sister paints/plays **at home**” - at home is a **non-core complement**. I prefer to make a distinction between complements and adjuncts, but even the definition of complements is problematic: “*a word, phrase, or clause that is necessary to complete the meaning of a given expression.[1] Complements are often also arguments (expressions that help complete the meaning of a predicate)”[2]*. The first sense states it’s obligatory for meaning while the second sense states they’re obligatory for grammaticalness.

Comment: Another example: [We call Rachelle the boss](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(linguistics)) - (the boss) Predicative nominal as object complement. Personally I would classify “the boss” as an adjunct as “We call Rachelle” is technically grammatical but semantically incomplete. However it is clear that there are some grammarians that would call this a complement. And adjuncts and complements are often very hard to distinguish by grammarians in general. I guess the billion dollar question is: what’s the difference between a non-core complement and adjunct? But that’s a different Q.

Comment: [...] Though, I have asked how to distinguish between core and non-core complements on [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/452705/how-to-tell-if-something-is-a-core-complement-or-a-non-core-complement).

Comment: You need to tighten up the << quote >> I gave; it doesn't make sense. // CGEL has (p 680, reformatted & adjusted) ' _Location_: Location elements can be complements or adjuncts: ... (iiia')(COMP) the accident occurred [at home] / (iiib)(ADJ) I read the report at home'. Obviously, the test they use is 'Does the sentence without the element in question sound natural?' With my examples, 'My sister paints' sounds natural whereas 'My sister plays' sounds unnatural without artificial licensing context.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Do you admit then that your sentence can then be analysed as a complement by some grammars? I definitely agree with what you say, what you’re describing is an innate, intrinsic method used by native speakers, but the adverbial element (which can be seen as the adjunct or complement); “My sister paints” *Paints what?*; “My sister plays” *plays what?* still needs to be addressed. Are we going to base whether a sentence needs artificial licensing context through whether it sounds “natural” or through actual grammar/semantics etc.?

Comment: Anyone who downvoted, could they tell why? Thanks.

Comment: I already have done; you still haven't bothered to correct the grammar of << “At home” can also be analysed as prepositional phrases which act as verb-phrase complements to the verb >>.  And is 'at home' always an adjunct, always a complement, or sometimes one and sometimes the other? According to whose analysis/terminology? And do some grammarians class 'at home' as an adverb (even though it contains two words) when it is not classed as a complement ('He is at home' can hardly be said to contain an adverb/adverbial; I just label 'at home' here a ...

Comment: locative. 'He studies at home' obviously contains an adverb/adverbial, describing where he carries out his studying [or some of it].)

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth well it contradicts your first comment. Secondly, no one said “at home” was an adverb ... “adverbial”. My sentence of the post says “it **can** also be analysed”, I will make this more clearer which grammar analysis it is following. Now a true adverb is: “‘My sister plays **outside** - it’s a locative adverb; my analysis follows @ tchrist answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313033/object-or-adverb). [at home] is a locative *adverbial*.